# Проблемы с вызовом onClick в javascript

Tags: javascript, json, click

Необходимо вызывать функцию и в качестве параметра передавать ей конкретный элемент из массива json. Вод код

```
obj=JSON.parse("["+mas+"]")
        for (prop in obj) {
            output.push('<input type="button" onclick="copy(obj[prop].name)" value="Копировать"/>')
        }
```

В итоге в функцию copy идет первое значение из всего массива, а нужно на каждый input по порядку что бы приходило prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... в функцию copy идет первое значение из всего массива

Не первое, а последнее.

```
output.push(`<input type="button" onclick="copy('${obj[prop].name}')" value="Копировать"/>`);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 0):

В цикле попробуйте указать объявление переменной (`var` или `let`):

```
//...
for (var prop in obj) {
//...
```

Comment: не, все ок  ее раньше объявил